# Unicorn with Rails, error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicorn

I'm trying in Ubuntu to use Unicorn with Rails but i have this error:

> E, [2013-11-23T17:18:03.975416 #20734] ERROR -- : couldn't find HOME
>   environment -- expanding `~' (ArgumentError)

How can i fix this?

Comment: When do you get this error?  During startup of unicorn?  Is there anything in the log files?

Comment: I get this error from the log of Unicorn when run. This is the entire log: https://gist.github.com/simonini/7624800

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the gem guard, i commented it in Gemfile and now i dont have more that problem.